# set permission and owner for file in php

Tags: php, file-permissions

I want create a directory for every user when user registered .and set permission for that directory only for one user.chown() php function apply permission for apache user.but i search for way to apply permission for user registered in php.
can anyone help me ?

Comment: Why are you using unix file ownership/permissions? Seems rather complex for system admin. Just implement it though your web interface (MySql database perhaps)

Comment: assume when a user registered by user1 username .I must to create a directory called dirforuser1 .now I have to set ownership of dirforuse1 to user1 and  your mean is I should not use unix file ownership/permission.if I should not use unix file ownership/permission can you suggest to me a better method?

Comment: I guess the only access is via the web server. That can do the control of access. PS use account numbers - Saves problems when users come and go with the same username